# Django Admin: How to merge items with same name to simplify view

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Big Django newbie here.

I have an admin view grouping items like this, tho as the number of bids grows it would be tiresome for one to scroll down all the items, so I wanted to group them by the item names that once clicked would show the columns 'bidder' and 'value'.

The Admin page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/51W4Z.png

I was looking into aggregate and annotate to merge them. Am I looking for the right thing?

The model in question is this:

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Auction_Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items', related_query_name='item')
    bidder = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bidders', related_query_name='bidder')
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.item}"
```

In the Admin I got:

```
class BidAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('item', 'bidder', 'value')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super(BidAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).order_by('item')
        return queryset
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit simple but why don't you limit the number of bids shown in the admin view? I'm sure you're not interested in all of them, so why display them? You could probably paginated the admin list view aswell if you customise the template.

Comment: I could, but for the requirements of this exercise the admin needs to be able to edit any bids if they want.
It would be nice to learn how to output it the way I was asking in any case.